magento 2 how to save custom field in sales order grid table?
I have created custom column in sales_order_grid table if I save data in that column not saved but it was saved in sales_order table

Can you explain your code here?

Try the following way to copy field delivery_note value automatically when saving the sales_order table:

VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--Copy 'delivery_note' to sales_order_grid table -->
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="delivery_note" xsi:type="string">sales_order.delivery_note</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>


Working @Supravat Mondal Thank you so much
